# How to `Reduce` an inequality with `QuantityVariable`s?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, curated-data, units

Without `QuantityVariable`s I can `Reduce` a `Quantity` inequality.

```
Reduce[(w == Quantity[3, "Meters"] || w == Quantity[-3, "Meters"]) &&
   w > Quantity[0, "Meters"]]
```

> ```
>  w == Quantity[3, "Meters"]
> ```

However with `QuantityVariable`s a similar inequality will not reduce.

```
Reduce[(FormulaData[
    "PythagoreanTheorem", 
    {"a" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"], 
     "b" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"]}]) && 
  QuantityVariable["c", "Length"] > Quantity[0, "Meters"]]
```

This returns with the `Reduce` unevaluated.

How do you reduce an inequality containing `QuantityVariable`s?

Comment: `Simplify[FormulaData[
  "PythagoreanTheorem", {"a" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"], 
   "b" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"]}], 
 QuantityVariable["c", "Length"] > Quantity[0, "Meters"]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Nice approach. Post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) with the [`QuantityVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityVariable.html) inequality as an assumption to the `Simplify`

```
Simplify[FormulaData[
  "PythagoreanTheorem", {"a" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"], 
   "b" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"]}], 
 QuantityVariable["c", "Length"] > Quantity[0, "Meters"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach.  May I ask how you knew to use Simplify in place of Reduce here?  Are there specific classes of problems for which Simplify gives a solution when Reduce fails?

Comment: @theorist - `Reduce` could be used, i.e. `Reduce[(FormulaData[
    "PythagoreanTheorem", {"a" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"], 
     "b" -> Quantity[250, "Meters"]}]) && 
  QuantityVariable["c", "Length"] > Quantity[0, "Meters"], 
 QuantityVariable["c", "Length"]]`; however, this appeared unnecessarily long and I looked for a shorter solution. Since the ultimate goal was to simplify a boolean expression, trying `Simplify` (or, if necessary, `FullSimplify`) seemed appropriate.

Comment: Ah, so the problem with Edmund's formulation of Reduce was merely that he hadn't specified the var. to be solved for—understandable since, when there's only one unknown, Reduce doesn't typically need this. E.g. `Reduce[3 x^2 == 10]` works as well as `Reduce[3 x^2 == 10, x]`. Yet, it seems when we use QuantityVariable (QV), the var. specification becomes necessary: `Reduce[3 QuantityVariable["x", "Length"]^2 == 10]` doesn't work, but `Reduce[3 QuantityVariable["x", "Length"]^2 == 10, 
 QuantityVariable["x", "Length"]]` does—perhaps b/c Reduce's code doesn't recognize a QV as a var. on its own.

Comment: @theorist - `QuantityVariable` has only been around since v10.0 Presumably, `Reduce` just hasn't been adjusted to its presence yet.